# Duplicate site of Stack Overflow or don't know what to call it

Tags: discussion

As usual as I was trying to find some solution on Google and the first preference being Stack Overflow, I read one of the question/answer there and decided to see other web results.

[Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489654/parent-window-location-redirection-from-spring-mvc-modelandview)

And then I came to this site with same question and answer:

[Resolvinghere page](http://www.resolvinghere.com/sof/4489654.shtml)

This has the same question and answer which was there on Stack Overflow page which I saw before.

I am just wondering: What site is that? Is it a duplicate of Stack Overflow? Doesn't have the same look and feel, but all the content seems to be from Stack Overflow.

Comment: That site (resolvinghere) is simply awful...the design is horrid at best.